# How to use two different realm configurations

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I'm working with the default realm instance, which contains some schemas. Now, I want to create a new schema in a different realm instance. So I have created a new Realm configuration, and when I query or store entities for this new schema, I use the new configuration, instead of the default one. In this way, I expect to avoid the neeed of create a migration for the new schema, due to I use it with a different database. But when I use the default realm instance, an exception is thrown (RealmMigrationNeededException), which tells me that I have to create a migration for my new schema. Can I avoid that in any way if I want to work with my new schema only in a new database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check Realm's document:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas

You need to define your 2 custom modules for different configurations.
For example, configB only cares about Cat.class schema.

```
// Create my module A
@RealmModule(classes = { Person.class, Dog.class })
public class MyModule {
}

// Create the module B
@RealmModule(classes = { Cat.class })
public class MyOtherModule {
}

// Set the module in the RealmConfiguration to allow only classes defined by the module.
RealmConfiguration configA = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .modules(new MyModule())
  .name("A.realm")
  .build();

RealmConfiguration configB = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .modules(new MyOtherModule())
  .name("B.realm")
  .build();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was looking for.